# why elasticsearch lost items after index?

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child, sense

I trying a small example

I create a mappings

```
PUT /company
{
  "mappings": {
    "country": {},
    "branch": {
        "_parent": {
           "type": "country"
        }
    },
    "employee": {
        "_parent": {
            "type": "branch" 
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And add some item

```
POST /company/country/_bulk
{"index": {"_id": "countryA"}}
{"name": "0001"}
{"index": {"_id": "countryB"}}
{"name": "0008"}
{"index": {"_id": "countryC"}}
{"name": "0015"}

POST /company/branch/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": "branchA", "parent": "countryA" }}
{ "name": "0002" }
{ "index": { "_id": "branchB", "parent": "countryA" }}
{ "name": "0005" }
{ "index": { "_id": "branchA", "parent": "countryB" }}
{ "name": "0009" }
{ "index": { "_id": "branchB", "parent": "countryB" }}
{ "name": "0012" }
{ "index": { "_id": "branchA", "parent": "countryC" }}
{ "name": "0016" }
{ "index": { "_id": "branchB", "parent": "countryC" }}
{ "name": "0019" }
```

But, then i run request

```
GET /company/branch/_search
```

result only 4 item branch

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 4,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "company",
            "_type": "branch",
            "_id": "branchA",
            "_score": 1,
            "_routing": "countryC",
            "_parent": "countryC",
            "_source": {
               "name": "0016"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "company",
            "_type": "branch",
            "_id": "branchB",
            "_score": 1,
            "_routing": "countryC",
            "_parent": "countryC",
            "_source": {
               "name": "0019"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "company",
            "_type": "branch",
            "_id": "branchA",
            "_score": 1,
            "_routing": "countryB",
            "_parent": "countryB",
            "_source": {
               "name": "0009"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "company",
            "_type": "branch",
            "_id": "branchB",
            "_score": 1,
            "_routing": "countryB",
            "_parent": "countryB",
            "_source": {
               "name": "0012"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**why, lost pair countryA-branchA & countryA-branchB?**

*ps: i try again sometime, may be countryA conflicting with countryB*

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're 'losing' documents is because you give more than one document the same `_id`. In Elasticsearch, document ids are unique, when you're inserting two documents using the same document id, the second insert will overwrite and update the first record.

If you execute `GET /company/branch/branchA` you will be able to see the that document `_version` is greater than 1.

To solve this, simply either remove the `_id` attribute and let Elasticsearch generate the id automatically, or choose unique document ids for each document.

Comment: why? i added 3 id dupplicate. But, lost 1 and exist 2. Why not 1.

Answer (score 0):

In this case Elasticsearch losing records with the same `_id` and the same `_parent` (record is identified by `_id`+`_parent`).
If there is no `_parent` (branching), so use only `_id` field to identify record.